# Making obstacles that follow the same rule move individually

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am writing a "simple" game and i can't figure out how to solve this problem where the red obstacles can't go alone from the upper part to the lower part of the screen. 
I included both the function(which simply makes the obstacles go over the window) and the actual part i am using(which make the ostacles change direction simultaneusly)

I tried for 2 hours using for and while loops but i couldn't solve it

```
lista_ost = [[some value for the x, some value for the y],[some value for the x, some value for the y]] 
def mov_ost(vel_ost,altezza,ost_grandezza,lista_ost):
    for i in lista_ost:
         i[1] += vel_ost
         if i[1] >= (altezza - ost_grandezza):
             vel_ost = -10

         elif i[1] <= 0:
             vel_ost = 10

while not game_over:

    numero_nemici(lista_ost, spazio_corsie, n_corsie)
    aggiungi_nemici(lista_ost)
    for ost_pos in lista_ost:
        ost_pos[1] += vel_ost
        if ost_pos[1] >= ((altezza - ost_grandezza)):
            vel_ost = -10
```

I expect the obstacles to move individually, but as I said they go as a group, all together.

Comment: Using [Sprite Groups](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) will make things easier for you. Creating a [mcve] will make it easier to assist you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my Italian is limited, but my understanding of the question code is that an obect should have a movement path `lista_ost` which contains a bunch of co-ordinates that govern the movements of on-screen objects.  (I hope that's correct!)

As @Eric said in a comment, an easy way to handle on-screen objects is with a [PyGame sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), and if there's more than one, use a [sprite group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).

So in the example code below, the code creates a group of `EnemySprite` objects.  These are made with an on-screen image, and a `move_path`.  This `move_path` is a list of adjustments to the sprite's co-ordinates.  Each time the sprite `EnemySprite.update()` function is called, the *next* co-ordinate update is applied to the current position of the `sprite.rect` (which is ultimately the sprite's on-screen `[x,y]`).  When the co-ordinates list is all used, it starts at the first element again.

This allows us to give the sprite a path to follow on screen.  To make a quick movement-path to put in the program, this code tracks the mouse, then dumps out a list of relative co-ordinates on exit.  To make the loopy path used in the example, I just dragged a loop through the window with the mouse, then edited it into the code.  I could have made the path manually on graph-paper of course.

```
import pygame
import random

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH      = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT     = 400

SPACE_BLUE = ( 23,  55,  84)


# Global millisecond count since start
NOW_MS = 0

class EnemySprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, image, move_path = [ (1, 1) ] ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image      = image
        self.rect       = self.image.get_rect()
        self.path       = move_path
        self.path_index = 0
        # Start position is randomly across the screen, and a little off the top
        self.rect.center   = ( random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH ), random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )

    def wrapAroundScreen(self):
        """ Ensure the sprite's position remains on-screen,
            wrapping around if necessary """
        if (self.rect.left >= WINDOW_WIDTH ):
            self.rect.right = 0
        elif (self.rect.right <= 0 ):
            self.rect.left = WINDOW_WIDTH
        if (self.rect.top >= WINDOW_HEIGHT ):
            self.rect.bottom = 0
        elif (self.rect.bottom <= 0):
            self.rect.top = WINDOW_HEIGHT

    def update(self):
        """ Move the sprite, by adjusting the poistion by the next 
            pair of offsets in the movement path """
        x,y = self.rect.center # Where is the drop, right now
        ### Get the next movement offsets.  
        offset = self.path[ self.path_index ]
        self.path_index += 1
        ### If we have run out of path offsets, start again
        if ( self.path_index >= len( self.path ) ):
            self.path_index = 0
        self.rect.center = ( x + offset[0], y + offset[1] )
        self.wrapAroundScreen()




### MAIN
pygame.init()
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption( "Path Following" )


# Add some enemy sprites
LOOPY_PATH = [  (18,0), (15,0), (12,0), (13,0), (13,0), (12,-3), (14,-2), (11,-4), (7,-2), (8,-3), (9,-3), (9,-5), (9,-3), (9,-6), (9,-5), (10,-8), (9,-5), (9,-4), (8,-5), (4,-3), (5,-4), (2,-3), (1,-3), (0,-6), (2,-7), (1,-5), (1,-4), (0,-5), (0,-3), (-1,-4), (-2,-4), (-3,-4), (-5,-5), (-4,-4), (-4,-2), (-7,-3), (-7,-1), (-9,-1), (-11,0), (-9,0), (-8,0), (-5,1), (-5,3), (-5,3), (-5,4), (-4,4), (-5,4), (-3,7), (-1,6), (0,6), (0,6), (1,6), (3,5), (3,6), (4,7), (4,7), (7,8), (5,9), (7,6), (11,6), (14,7), (15,5), (16,4), (17,4), (18,2), (20,3), (18,2), (20,1), (20,0), (19,0), (23,0), (22,0), (12,0) ]
ENEMY_IMAGE = pygame.image.load( 'tiny_alien.png' )
SPRITES = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(10):
    SPRITES.add( EnemySprite( ENEMY_IMAGE, LOOPY_PATH ) )

mouse_path = []

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:
    NOW_MS = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # re-position all the drops
    SPRITES.update()

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )

    # Record mouse movements for new paths
    new_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if ( new_pos != (0,0) ):
        mouse_path.append( new_pos )

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        print("up")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
        print("down")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
        print("left")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
        print("right")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_q] and ( keys[pygame.K_RCTRL] or keys[pygame.K_LCTRL] ) ):
        print("^Q")
        done = True

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    WINDOW.fill( SPACE_BLUE )
    SPRITES.draw( WINDOW )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

### Print the relative co-orinates of the mouse moving through the window
### just in case the user was recording a path to use on the sprites
print( "Mouse Movement Path: ")
print( "[", end='' )
for i in range(1, len(mouse_path)):
    print("(%d,%d), " %( mouse_path[i][0] - mouse_path[i-1][0], mouse_path[i][1] - mouse_path[i-1][1]), end='')
print( " ]" )

pygame.quit()
```

This example produces somewhat erratic movement, but given it's following a mouse-drag over the window, it's OK.

Any small PNG image can be substituted for `tiny_alien.png`.

[image: animated jif of pygame window]